# How to align text inside the div tag with the links.

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the text inside the div tag with the links but I am unable to do it. Please take a look at the fiddle. Images are a little up than the text Page 5 of 6.

```
<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.full" value='<span class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{2}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> </a> | Page {5} of {6} | <a href="{3}">  <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{4}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> </a></span>'/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.first" value='<span class="pagelinks"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/>&nbsp | Page {5} of {6} | &nbsp<a href="{3}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{4}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> </a></span>'/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.last" value='<span class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{2}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> </a> | Page {5} of {6} | <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> </span>'/>
```

CSS

```
.pagelinks  {
float: right;
margin-right: 48%;
display: inline-block;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: #828282;
}

.pagelinks a {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
background-repeat:  no-repeat;
}
```

Thanks

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssadat/4q6h8czs/)

Comment: are you trying to vertically align like this? https://jsfiddle.net/4q6h8czs/1/

Comment: please format your code

Comment: @Michael Coker, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with flexbox:

```
.pagelinks  {
  display: flex;
  /* vertical centering on flex row content */
  align-items: center;
  /* horizontal centering on flex row content*/
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that at all. Awesome learning curve. Thanks Sean. You made my day.

Comment: No problem! Flexbox is awesome.